# Why is MongooseJS not pushing to array?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mlab

**HERE IS THE SCHEMA**

```
const DollSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        firstName: {type:String, trim:true},
        lastName: {type:String, trim:true},
        stabCount: {type:Number},
        isActive: {type:Boolean},
        curses: [{type: String}]
    });

const Doll = mongoose.model('doll', DollSchema);
```

**HERE IS THE CODE THAT SHOULD PUSH IT TO THE ARRAY**

```
Doll.findOne({firstName:req.body.firstName, lastName:req.body.lastName})
    .then(dolls => dolls.curses.push(req.body.curse))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: In the schema, curses is defined as an String, and you are trying to push Array.

Comment: After pumping into the array add the save ():  `dolls.save()`

Comment: I changed string to array and it did not fix my problem

Comment: thanks JustCase7 I thought the push method was equivalent to saving. That worked thank you so much!